# Laravel couldn't verify created user for login

Tags: laravel

in this simple code i created function to created users into database, after created them i can't verify `username` and `password` there and i get `false`

```
public function store(RequestUsers $request)
{
    $user = User::create(array_merge($request->all(), ['username'=>'testtest', 'password' => bcrypt('testtest')]));

    if ($user->id) {

        dd(auth()->validate(['username'=>'testtest','password'=>$user->password]));

    } else {

    }
}
```

what's problem of my code which i can't verify created user?

full my login controller:

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validateLogin($request);

        if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
            $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

            return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
        }

        if (auth()->validate($request->only('username','password'))) {
            $user = User::whereUsername($request->username)->first();

            if ($user->lock) {
                $request->session()->flash('error',__('message.your_account_locked'));
                return view('layouts.backend.pages.auth.account.locked_account');
            }elseif (!$user->active) {
                $checkActivationCode = $user->activationCode()->where('expire', '>=', Carbon::now())->latest()->first();

                if ($checkActivationCode != null) {
                    if ($checkActivationCode->expire > Carbon::now()) {
                        $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);

                        $request->session()->flash('error',__('message.please_active_your_account'));
                        return view('layouts.backend.pages.auth.account.active_account');
                    }
                }else{
                    return redirect()->to('/page/userAccountActivation/create');
                }
            }
        }

        if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {
            //dd('aaaaaa');
            return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
        }

        $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);

        return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
    }

    public function redirectToProvider()
    {
        return Socialite::driver('google')->redirect();
    }

    public function handleProviderCallback()
    {
        $socialUser = Socialite::driver('google')->stateless()->user();
        $user = User::whereEmail($socialUser->getEmail())->first();

        //dd($socialUser->getAvatar());

        if (!$user) {
            $data = [
                'name' => $socialUser->getName(),
                'email' => $socialUser->getEmail(),
                'avatar' => str_replace('sz=50', 'sz=150', $socialUser->getAvatar()),
                'mobileNumber' => '',
                'loginType'=>'google',
                'password' => bcrypt($socialUser->getId()),
            ];

            //dd($data);
            $user = User::create($data);
        }

        if ($user->active == 0) {
            $user->update([
                'active' => 1
            ]);
        }

        auth()->loginUsingId($user->id);
        return redirect('/system/UserLoginWithGoogle');
    }

    public function show()
    {
        return view('auth.login');
    }

    protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'username' => 'required|string',
            'password' => 'required|string',
            'g-recaptcha-response', 'recaptcha'
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: password passed to auth validate needs to be plain text password, not the hashed password. `'password'=>$user->password` would be the hashed password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `dd(auth()->validate(['username'=>'testtest','password'=>$user->password]));`

Validate method expects the array to hold plain text value for the password. `$user->password` would be the hashed value, and it will always return false for that reason.

Changing that to:

```
dd(auth()->validate(['username'=>'testtest','password'=>'testtest']));
```

should yield the desired output.

Comment: i get `false` again

Comment: I couldn't notice any other errors, sorry. What data does the `$request` contain. Anything that would override username or password?